# Consulta en Big Query para que muestre el ultimo evento

Tags: sql

tengo la siguiente consulta quisiera poder filtrar en Big Query para toda una tabla el ultimo registro de un ID, el ID se repite porque tiene varios Eventos, pero solo quiero tome en cuenta para todos los registros el ultimo evento probé con un Distinct pero no funciona ya que se repite el id para cada evento

`select  a.order_id as OrdenId,b.FechaPreparacion as FechaFulfilled,a.fulfillment_id as  IdFulfillment,a.happened_at as FechaEntrega, a.status as Estado, from fulfillment_event a inner join PrepPedidos b on a.order_id = b.OrderId where status= 'delivered' order by a.happened_at desc`

el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con la cláusula LIMIT y la cantidad de registros que quieres, en este caso 1:

```
select  a.order_id as OrdenId,b.FechaPreparacion asFechaFulfilled,a.fulfillment_id as IdFulfillment,a.happened_at as FechaEntrega, a.status as Estado, 
from fulfillment_event a 
inner join PrepPedidos b on a.order_id = b.OrderId 
where status= 'delivered' 
order by a.happened_at desc 
LIMIT 1
```